# Console.Clear() doesn't clear the whole console window

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I'm writing a simple program and i want to clear the whole console window with Console.Clear() but it only deletes the lines i wrote in the same method. It doesn't delete the previous lines.

Any ideas?

The code (line 123.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Szigeti_Marton_FW0S9E
{
    //Reversi (Othello) - Szigeti Márton, FW0S9E

    class Game
    {
        private int[,] Table { get; set; }

        private int gameCounter { get; set; }

        private const int dimX = 8;
        private const int dimY = 8;

        private const char playerSign = 'X';
        private const char computerSign = 'O';

        private void Map()
        {
            Console.Write("  ");

            for(int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
                Console.Write("{0} ", (char)(65 + k));

            Console.WriteLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < dimX; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(i+1);

                for (int j = 0; j <= dimY; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("| ");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        private void Map(int x, int y, char sign)
        {
            //Overloaded

            Console.Write("  ");

            for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
                Console.Write("{0} ", (char)(65 + k));

            Console.WriteLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < dimX; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(i + 1);

                for (int j = 0; j <= dimY; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("| ");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        private bool isFieldEmpty(int x, int y)
        {
            if (Table[x, y] == -1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        private bool isInputValid(string input)
        {
            bool temp = true;

            bool tempLetter = false, tempNumber = false;

            if ((input.Length == 2) && (char.IsLetter(input[0])) && (char.IsNumber(input[1])))
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < dimX; i++)
                {
                    if (input[0] == (char)65 + i)
                        tempLetter = true;
                }

                if (!tempLetter)
                    temp = false;

                for (int j = 0; j < dimY; j++)
                {
                    if (int.Parse(input[1].ToString()) == j)
                        tempNumber = true;
                }

                if (!tempNumber)
                    temp = false;
            }
            else if (input.Length != 2)
                temp = false;

            return temp;
        }

        private void makeAMove()
        {
            int tempLetter = 0;

            gameCounter++;
            string Field;
            Random randomMove = new Random();

            Console.WriteLine("Adjon meg egy mezőt, pl. \"D3\". Feladáshoz: \"feladom\"");

            do { Field = Console.ReadLine(); }
            while (!isInputValid(Field));

            Console.Clear(); // <-- Line 123

            if (gameCounter % 2 == 1)
            {
                Field[0].ToString().ToUpper();

                for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                    if(Field[0] == (char)(65+i))
                        tempLetter = i;

                Map(Field[1], tempLetter, playerSign);
            }
            else if (gameCounter % 2 == 0)
            {
                //Gép random lépés
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Game Player1 = new Game();
            Player1.Map();
            Player1.makeAMove();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I put a link to the code

Comment: You really should localize the issue and do not post a link to several screens worth of code if you expect to get an answer

Comment: Just imagine two methods in a class. There's a writeline in method one which you call. Then there's a writeline in method two which you also call. In method two, there's the Console.Clear(). It only clears the text you wrote out in the same method you called the Console.Clear(). So it only clears the method two text. The method one text is still there in the beginning. Pretty easy to understand.

Comment: You are wrong, see answer below

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `Console.Clear()` isn't really working is because of the do-while statement in the method.  (Line 120 and Line 121).

Move the `Console.Clear();` above the do-while statement (probably Line 120) and it will work.

The reason the do-while is blocking the `Console.clear()` is that in the do statement, it is expecting an input and in the while statement it is expecting the input to satisfy a condition

```
do { Field = Console.ReadLine(); } 
while (!isInputValid(Field));)
```

Without that input and until the condition in the while is satisfied, It won't proceed to the next statement.

Comment: The only problem is that i can't do that, becouse at that point i need to see the map, so i can't clear the console before the do-while. Maybe the do-while is not correct? I'm not sure.

Comment: @mszigetihu The reason the do-while is blocking the console.clear is that in the do statement, it is expecting an input. (`do { Field = Console.ReadLine(); }
            while (!isInputValid(Field));`) Without that input and until the condition in the while is fulfilled, It won't proceed. You need to work on that

Comment: @mszigetihu To confirm. When the code gets to the part of the do while and the console.clear isn't executing. Enter `3b` in the console and press enter. It will execute the Console.Clear() and the remaining code

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("0");
        Test1();
        Test2();
    }

    public static void Test1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
    }

    public static void Test2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2");
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("3");
    }
```

Output is:

```
3
```

The problem is not in `Console.Clear` but in your logic

Answer (score -3):

Hope This Help :

```
 using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace nsClearConsole
{
   /// <summary>
  /// Summary description for ClearConsole.
  /// </summary><BR/>
   public class ClearConsole
  {     
     private const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE  = -11;
     private const byte EMPTY = 32;

     [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
     struct COORD
     {
        public short x;
        public short y;
     }

     [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
     struct SMALL_RECT
     {
        public short Left;
        public short Top;
        public short Right;
        public short Bottom;
     }

     [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
     struct CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO
     {
        public COORD dwSize;
        public COORD dwCursorPosition;
        public int wAttributes;
        public SMALL_RECT srWindow;
        public COORD dwMaximumWindowSize;
     }

     [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="GetStdHandle", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
     private static extern int GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

     [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="FillConsoleOutputCharacter", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
     private static extern int FillConsoleOutputCharacter(int hConsoleOutput, byte cCharacter, int nLength, COORD dwWriteCoord, ref int lpNumberOfCharsWritten);

     [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
     private static extern int GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(int hConsoleOutput, ref CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo);

     [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="SetConsoleCursorPosition", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
     private static extern int SetConsoleCursorPosition(int hConsoleOutput, COORD dwCursorPosition);

     private int hConsoleHandle;

     public ClearConsole()
     {
        // 
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here.
        // 
        hConsoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
     }

     public void Clear()
     {
        int hWrittenChars = 0;
        CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO strConsoleInfo = new CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO();           
        COORD Home;     
        Home.x = Home.y = 0;
        GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsoleHandle, ref strConsoleInfo);
        FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsoleHandle, EMPTY, strConsoleInfo.dwSize.x * strConsoleInfo.dwSize.y, Home, ref hWrittenChars);
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsoleHandle, Home);
     }
  }
}
```

See This For More Information :
     http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319257

Comment: Thanks, but it's not helping. Switching a one line method with this.. no thanks?